# "Refreshing" SharedObject

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I stuffed it while testing my program and I want it to be "fresh" when I export the game. Is that possible? I mean, in my current project, SharedObject has already lots of information when it should be empty when being ran first time on computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use new name for your object or simple use .clear function. Dont forget to remove clear function before publish.

```
var _sharedObj:SharedObject;
try
{
  _sharedObj = SharedObject.getLocal("yourobjectname");
}
catch (error:Error)
{
  trace("SharedObject Error:"+error.toString());
  return;
}

_sharedObj.clear();
```

clear():void
For local shared objects, purges all of the data and deletes the shared object from the disk.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6